# Mathematics to learn for applying for undergraduate computer science

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What are the resources, books or papers you would recommend that would help me 'wow' Computer Science undergraduate admissions when I apply next year?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking into maximize your chances of admission or maximize your chances of success in the Math courses, if admited?

Comment: You're applying to undergraduate or graduate school?

Comment: Git Gud - Admission.    
icurays 1 - Undergraduate.
:-)

Comment: @CameronAllan: do you have any objection to this question being made [Community Wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/community-wiki)?

Answer (score 4):

I would certainly highly recommend looking at the schools you are applying to and making sure you meet the entrance requirements for the math courses. Look at the CS Math courses and see where you stand with the math they require (where are your deficiencies).

Additionally, I would look to some of the schools that specialize in CS and see what they require for students at either the undergraduate or graduate level (depending on which you are). You can see a detailed list of those schools [*US News' - World's Best Universities for CS*](http://www.usnews.com/education/worlds-best-universities-rankings/best-universities-computer-science).

In general terms, you might want to review:

$\bullet$ [*Recomendation for Math books related to computer science on SO*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66764/recomendation-for-math-books-related-to-computer-science)

$\bullet$ [*canonical-book-on-mathematics-for-programmers on SO*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/85506/is-there-a-canonical-book-on-mathematics-for-programmers)

You might also want to look for online notes, for example:

$\bullet$ [*Mathematics for Computer Science*](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr10/cos433/mathcs.pdf)

Lastly, you may also want to explore [*Open Course Ware*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCourseWare), for example at [*MIT*](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm).

Regards

Comment: *Spot on* recommendations!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for the support my friend, I am currently freaking out about my talk this week cause still needs polishing! Regards